# Custom pattern-matching facility for Chez Scheme

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, scheme, s-expression, define-syntax

I am trying to make my own pattern-matching system in Scheme. To begin I am making a parser for s-expressions that divides them into tokens like this:

`'(1 2 b (3 4))` => `'(number number symbol (number number))`

It should be noted that I have not used `define-syntax` before in Scheme so that may be where I am messing up. Chez Scheme throws me this error:
`Exception: invalid syntax classify at line 21, char 4 of pmatch.scm`. Note that the line numbers won't correspond exactly to the snippet here. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```lisp
(define-syntax classify
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ checker replacement)
     ((checker (car sexpr)) (cons replacement (classify-sexpr (cdr sexpr)))))))

(define (classify-sexpr sexpr)
    (cond
        ((null? sexpr) sexpr)
        (classify list? (classify-sexpr (car sexpr)))
        (classify number? 'number)
        (classify symbol? 'symbol)
        (else
          (cons 'symbol (classify-sexpr (cdr sexpr))))))

(display (classify-sexpr '(1 (b 3) (4 5) 6)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hugely confused.  In fact it's so confused I'm not sure what you're trying to do completely: I've based my answer on what you say the classifier should produce at the start of your question.

- First of all your macro refers to `sexpr` which has no meaning in the macro, and because Scheme macros are hygienic it will definitely not refer to the `sexpr` which is the argument to `classify-sexpr`.
- Secondly you don't need a macro at all here.  I suspect that you may be thinking that because you are trying to *write* a macro you must use macros in its construction: that's not necessarily true and often a bad idea.
- Thirdly the syntax of your `cond` is botched beyond repair: I can't work out what it's trying to do.
- Finally the `list` classification will never be needed: if you want to classify `(1 2 3 (x))` as `(number number number (symbol))` then you'll simply never reach a case where you have a list which you want to classify since you must walk into it to classify its elements.

Instead just write the obvious functions do do what you want:

```
(define classification-rules
  ;; an alist of predicate / replacement which drives classigy
  `((,number? number)
    (,symbol? symbol)))
    
(define (classify thing)
  ;; classify thing using classification-rules
  (let loop ([tail classification-rules])
    (cond [(null? tail)
           'something]
          [((first (first tail)) thing)
           (second (first tail))]
          [else
           (loop (rest tail))])))

(define (classify-sexpr sexpr)
  ;; classify a sexpr using classify.
  (cond
    [(null? sexpr) '()]
    [(cons? sexpr) (cons (classify-sexpr (car sexpr))
                         (classify-sexpr (cdr sexpr)))]
    [else (classify sexpr)]))
```

And now

```
> (classify-sexpr '(1 2 3 (x 2) y))
'(number number number (symbol number) symbol)
```

It may be that what you really want is something which classifies `(1 2 (x 2))` as `(list number number (list symbol number))` say.  You can do this fairly easily:

```
(define atomic-classification-rules
  ;; an alist of predicate / replacements for non-conses
  `((,number? number)
    (,symbol? symbol)))
    
(define (classify-sexpr sexpr)
  (cond
    [(null? sexpr) '()]
    [(list? sexpr)
     `(list ,@(map classify-sexpr sexpr))]
    [(cons? sexpr)
     `(cons ,(classify-sexpr (car sexpr))
            ,(classify-sexpr (cdr sexpr)))]
    [else
     (let caloop ([rtail atomic-classification-rules])
       (cond [(null? rtail)
              'unknown]
             [((first (first rtail)) sexpr)
              (second (first rtail))]
             [else
              (caloop (rest rtail))]))]))
```

And now

```
> (classify-sexpr '(1 2 3 (x 2) y))
'(list number number number (list symbol number) symbol)
> (classify-sexpr '(1 2 3 (x 2) . y))
'(cons number (cons number (cons number (cons (list symbol number) symbol))))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I see how confusing my intent was now; I have since found a much simpler way to achieve pattern matching.